# No contacts after importing a WAB file

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-mail, outlook-express

I'm trying to import a WAB file (Outlook Express contacts) into Windows 7. The file is 173 KB and definitely has lots of contacts in it. However, once it's been imported the only contact that's in the Contacts folder is that of the computer owner, this may well have been there before the import was attempted.

All the messages that pop up are positive and make it look like the import has succeeded, but it doesn't look like contacts are added, even after a restart.

I've tried importing it by double clicking on the file, and through the Import menu option in Contacts. Neither has worked correctly.

Comment: Maybe the file's corrupted? (Although it should show an error if that's the case.) If you have access to a PC with OE see if the WAB opens there. If so, maybe you can try exporting as vCard (VCF) or some other format that WLM can import.